# tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, mysql, pythonanywhere

I'm running into this issue when using mySQL. My result = `[{'email': 'bernie@shrimp.com'}]` but I'm getting an `TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str` when I'm doing `email = results[0]['email']`

The thing is when I'm running this locally it works perfectly. How do I get `bernie@shrimp.com`?

users is a table

Code:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT email FROM users WHERE username = %s', [attempted_username])
email_dict = cursor.fetchall()
print(email_dict)
session['email'] = email_dict[0]['email']
```

Console:

```
[{'email': 'bernie@shrimp.com'}]
```

Comment: May you edit the question with proper code as your variable names are not matching. such as My result and results.

Comment: I added some above - tell me if more is needed

Comment: the issue comes with or without sessions

Comment: your console output is confusing may you check if its [{}] or [()]

Comment: I copy and pasted @Harry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `fetchall` is a list of tuples, not a list of `dict`.

Your query result have only one field: email at index 0.

You can rewrite your code like this:

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    email = row[0]
```

Or, in your situation where there is only one result:

```
session['email'] = rows[0][0]
```

I think, you can also use:

```
row = cursor.one()
```

Comment: How do I get bernie@shrimp.com then?

Comment: won't row[0] will return 'email' instead of 'bernie@shrimp.com'

Comment: @Harry No, `row` is a `tuple` containing the **field values**, not a `dict`.

Comment: ohh sorry his console output confused me.

Answer (score 2):

This can work with extras.DictCursor:

```
cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory = psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
for fields in cur:
   print(fields['column_name'])
```

Answer (score 1):

`fetchall` returns a list of tupples. You need to access it by the column's ordinal, not its name:

```
session['email'] = email_dict[0][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dictionary=True` parameter in cursor() method call enables the use of a dictionary to represent rows instead of tuples.

```
cursor = connection.cursor(dictionary=True)
cursor.execute('SELECT email FROM users WHERE username = %s LIMIT 1', (attempted_username,))
email_dict = cursor.fetchone()
print(email_dict)
session['email'] = email_dict['email']
```